# Send int from Java to Arduino

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to send a int from my Java program to my Arduino board.
I got the Java code from http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java

Java code:

```java
package com.thetrialbot.arduinosteppercontrol;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier; 
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent; 
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener; 
import java.util.Enumeration;


public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
        /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = { 
            "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
                        "/dev/ttyACM0", // Raspberry Pi
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
            "COM3", // Windows
    };
    /**
    * A BufferedReader which will be fed by a InputStreamReader 
    * converting the bytes into characters 
    * making the displayed results codepage independent
    */
    private BufferedReader input;
    /** The output stream to the port */
    private OutputStream output;
    /** Milliseconds to block while waiting for port open */
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    /** Default bits per second for COM port. */
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
                // the next line is for Raspberry Pi and 
                // gets us into the while loop and was suggested here was suggested http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=32186
                //System.setProperty("gnu.io.rxtx.SerialPorts", "/dev/ttyACM0");

        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // open serial port, and use class name for the appName.
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);

            // set port parameters
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            // add event listeners
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * This should be called when you stop using the port.
     * This will prevent port locking on platforms like Linux.
     */
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle an event on the serial port. Read the data and print it.
     */
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
                output.write(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000 seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
}
```

Arduino code:

```cpp
#define led 13  // built-in LED
char inputBuffer[10];   
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("Hello world");
  delay(1000);
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.readBytes(inputBuffer, Serial.available());
    delay(5000);
    Serial.print(inputBuffer);
  }
}
```

Here's an image of the console, because the character won't paste properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the program on the Arduino side, so that it runs synchronized. The Arduino side is slowly enough without delays. The `delay( 5 );` is to get time for the calcutations and to collect pending input on the port. With the `inputBuffer` the incoming numbers get chopped up and parts get lost while overwritten from the next following part. To get the input char by char is fast enough for submitting only numbers.
The `"Hello world!"` should only be send one time?!

```
boolean show = false;
int c = 0;
int num = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin( 9600 );
  Serial.setTimeout( 450 );
  while( ! Serial ) {}
  Serial.println( "Hello world!" );
}

void loop() {
  while( Serial.available() > 0 ) {
    c = Serial.read();
    if( c != '\n' )   // only needed for terminal-programs
      num = num * 10 + (c - '0');
    if( Serial.available() == 0 )
      delay( 5 );  /* 2 */
    show = true;
  }
  if( show ) {
    Serial.println( num );
    Serial.flush();
    num = 0;
    show = false;
  }
}
```

From Java (here with a 7th scripting engine) the numbers 1…100 are send as string and changed into its numeric values on Arduino side – send back again to Java and printed out. For installation visit this sides [7th](https://7th-stone.com/index.php?id=14) [JSerial](https://github.com/thibautd/JSerial) and put the 3 jar files into the same directory. Start the *Seventh.jar* file. Cut and paste the program into the editor and press *Eval*.
The `1500 sleep` gives the Arduino time to open the port.

```
: numbers
  101 0 do
    i str$ portwrite
    portread type
  loop
;
"COM10" 9600 8 0 1 0  6 PORT a!
portopen
1500 sleep  (* 1 *)
numbers
portclose
```